# Symfony2 / Doctrine, A new entity was found through the relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

trying to fix this over 48 hours. I have an entity **BookingRequest.php** which content is:

```
<?php

namespace Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BookingRequest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="booking_request")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Repository\BookingRequestRepository")
 */
class BookingRequest
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="arrival", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $arrival;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="departure", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $departure;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="requestDate", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $requestDate;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rooms", type="integer")
     */
    private $rooms;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="minPricing", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $minPricing;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="maxPricing", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $maxPricing;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $customerName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerEmail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $customerEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerPhone", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $customerPhone;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $destinationCity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerCity;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\MissionConfig", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $missionConfig;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\TourismConfig", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $tourismConfig;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\RoomsConfig", mappedBy="bookingRequest")
     */
    private $roomsConfigs;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->setRequestDate(date("d/m/Y"));
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set arrival
     *
     * @param string $arrival
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setArrival($arrival)
    {
        $this->arrival = $arrival;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get arrival
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getArrival()
    {
        return $this->arrival;
    }

    /**
     * Set departure
     *
     * @param string $departure
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setDeparture($departure)
    {
        $this->departure = $departure;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get departure
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeparture()
    {
        return $this->departure;
    }

    /**
     * Set requestDate
     *
     * @param string $requestDate
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setRequestDate($requestDate)
    {
        $this->requestDate = $requestDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requestDate
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRequestDate()
    {
        return $this->requestDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set rooms
     *
     * @param integer $rooms
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setRooms($rooms)
    {
        $this->rooms = $rooms;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rooms
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRooms()
    {
        return $this->rooms;
    }

    /**
     * Set minPricing
     *
     * @param string $minPricing
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setMinPricing($minPricing)
    {
        $this->minPricing = $minPricing;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minPricing
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMinPricing()
    {
        return $this->minPricing;
    }

    /**
     * Set maxPricing
     *
     * @param string $maxPricing
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setMaxPricing($maxPricing)
    {
        $this->maxPricing = $maxPricing;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get maxPricing
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMaxPricing()
    {
        return $this->maxPricing;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerName
     *
     * @param string $customerName
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setCustomerName($customerName)
    {
        $this->customerName = $customerName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerEmail
     *
     * @param string $customerEmail
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setCustomerEmail($customerEmail)
    {
        $this->customerEmail = $customerEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerEmail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerEmail()
    {
        return $this->customerEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerPhone
     *
     * @param string $customerPhone
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setCustomerPhone($customerPhone)
    {
        $this->customerPhone = $customerPhone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerPhone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerPhone()
    {
        return $this->customerPhone;
    }

    /**
     * Set destinationCity
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City $destinationCity
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setDestinationCity(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City $destinationCity)
    {
        $this->destinationCity = $destinationCity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get destinationCity
     *
     * @return \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City
     */
    public function getDestinationCity()
    {
        return $this->destinationCity;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerCity
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City $customerCity
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setCustomerCity(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City $customerCity)
    {
        $this->customerCity = $customerCity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerCity
     *
     * @return \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\City
     */
    public function getCustomerCity()
    {
        return $this->customerCity;
    }

    /**
     * Set missionConfig
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\MissionConfig $missionConfig
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setMissionConfig(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\MissionConfig $missionConfig = null)
    {
        $this->missionConfig = $missionConfig;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get missionConfig
     *
     * @return \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\MissionConfig
     */
    public function getMissionConfig()
    {
        return $this->missionConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Set tourismConfig
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\TourismConfig $tourismConfig
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function setTourismConfig(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\TourismConfig $tourismConfig = null)
    {
        $this->tourismConfig = $tourismConfig;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tourismConfig
     *
     * @return \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\TourismConfig
     */
    public function getTourismConfig()
    {
        return $this->tourismConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Add roomsConfig
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\RoomsConfig $roomsConfig
     *
     * @return BookingRequest
     */
    public function addRoomsConfig(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\RoomsConfig $roomsConfig)
    {
        $this->roomsConfigs[] = $roomsConfig;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roomsConfig
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\RoomsConfig $roomsConfig
     */
    public function removeRoomsConfig(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\RoomsConfig $roomsConfig)
    {
        $this->roomsConfigs->removeElement($roomsConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Get roomsConfigs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRoomsConfigs()
    {
        return $this->roomsConfigs;
    }
}
```

and another entity **RoomsConfig.php**

```
<?php

namespace Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RoomsConfig
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="rooms_config")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Repository\RoomsConfigRepository")
 */
class RoomsConfig
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="airConditionner", type="boolean")
     */
    private $airConditionner;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="wifi", type="boolean")
     */
    private $wifi;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="balcony", type="boolean")
     */
    private $balcony;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tv", type="boolean")
     */
    private $tv;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest", inversedBy="roomsConfigs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $bookingRequest;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * Set airConditionner
     *
     * @param boolean $airConditionner
     *
     * @return RoomsConfig
     */
    public function setAirConditionner($airConditionner)
    {
        $this->airConditionner = $airConditionner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get airConditionner
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getAirConditionner()
    {
        return $this->airConditionner;
    }

    /**
     * Set wifi
     *
     * @param boolean $wifi
     *
     * @return RoomsConfig
     */
    public function setWifi($wifi)
    {
        $this->wifi = $wifi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wifi
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getWifi()
    {
        return $this->wifi;
    }

    /**
     * Set balcony
     *
     * @param boolean $balcony
     *
     * @return RoomsConfig
     */
    public function setBalcony($balcony)
    {
        $this->balcony = $balcony;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get balcony
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getBalcony()
    {
        return $this->balcony;
    }

    /**
     * Set tv
     *
     * @param boolean $tv
     *
     * @return RoomsConfig
     */
    public function setTv($tv)
    {
        $this->tv = $tv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tv
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getTv()
    {
        return $this->tv;
    }

    /**
     * Set bookingRequest
     *
     * @param \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest $bookingRequest
     *
     * @return RoomsConfig
     */
    public function setBookingRequest(\Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest $bookingRequest)
    {
        $this->bookingRequest = $bookingRequest;

        $bookingRequest->addRoomsConfig($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bookingRequest
     *
     * @return \Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest
     */
    public function getBookingRequest()
    {
        return $this->bookingRequest;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to persist a RoomsConfig entity, I got an error

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest#destinationCity' that was
>   not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: TIKO. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})

I don't need a cascade effect on City and BookingRequest relation, here is my **BookingRequestType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BookingRequestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('arrival', TextType::class)
            ->add('departure', TextType::class)
            ->add('rooms', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('customerName', TextType::class)
            ->add('customerEmail', TextType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('customerPhone', TextType::class)
            ->add('destinationCity', EntityType::class, array(
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'class' => 'KutiwaPlatformBundle:City'
            ))
            ->add('customerCity', EntityType::class, array(
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'class' => 'KutiwaPlatformBundle:City'
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Kutiwa\PlatformBundle\Entity\BookingRequest'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'kutiwa_platformbundle_bookingrequest';
    }


}
```

If I try to persist only BookingRequest entity, there is no problem, but when I persist RoomsConfig entity, I got that error. Help please. Thks.

Comment: "I don't need a cascade effect on City and BookingRequest relation", but your mapping explicitly says that. Could you tell us more about your models?

Comment: BookingRequest contains a reservation request: user info (name, phone, city), number of rooms reserved, I have already all the cities I need in database, that is why I can't have a cascade effect between City an BookingRequest. RoomsConfig is for each room reserved, it configuration, like user want a TV in this room, an air conditionner in another room

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before persist your **RoomsConfig**, try to use `findOneBy` to find **BookingRequest**, or whatever you use to find the entity, and then set the found entity with `setBookingRequest`.

Comment: There is any way to avoid this solution? because if an Entity has a los of relationships. I have to set all of them? Why Doctrine thinks that entities are new?

Comment: @Oscar I'm not sure why this happens, but if you don't want to make that findOneBy, which means you need to make another query in your DB, you can try with getReference method, which only prepare the object with the id of the entity, like this:
$this->_em->getReference('WhateverBundle:EntityName', $entity_id);