# Doctrine Tell me "new Entity was found" when i set a relationship ManyToOne but is not

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-forms

1. I have a Project with Symfony
2. Create a form for a ner entity.

   ```
   class EquipoType extends AbstractType{
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $equipo = new Equipo();

       $builder
       ->add('unidades', IntegerType::class)
       ->add('accionComercial', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\AccionComercial',
           'em' => 'adeq',
           'choices' => $equipo->getAccionComercial(),
           'choice_label' => 'nombre',
           'placeholder' => 'Elija Accion Comercial'
       ))
       ->add('modelo', TextType::class)
       ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
               'label' => 'Guardar Equipo',
               'attr' => array(
                   'class' => "btn btn-info",
                   'style' => "margin-top: 7px; margin-left:40%;"
               ))
       );

       $builder->get('modelo')
           ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
               function ($modelo) {
                   return $modelo ? $modelo->getModDescModelo() :  $modelo;
               },
               function ($modelo) use ($options) {
                   return $modelo ? $options['em']->getRepository(ModModelo::class)->findOneBy(array(
                       'modDescModelo' => $modelo
                   )) : $modelo;
               }
           ));
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\Equipo',
           'em' => "adeq"
       ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
       return 'appbundle_indicogpt_adelantoequipos_equipo';
    }
   }
   ```
3. This Entity has a relatuionship.
   *(Equipo has Modelo[oneToMany], Modelo has Many Equipos[oneToMany] )*

   ```
       class Equipo
   {
       /**
    * @var \AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modelo_id", referencedColumnName="MOD_ID_MODELO")
    * })
    */
   private $modelo;
   ```
4. The entity *Modelo* is full of rows (in db) with types of equip models. Ergo an *Equipo* only need to save an existing Id of a *Modelo* row.

The problem appears when i do `$emAedq->flush()` Here is my controller:

```
    public function crearEquipo(Request $request){

     $emAdeq = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('adeq');
     $emCatalogo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('catalogo');

     $equipo = new Equipo();
     $form = $this->createForm(EquipoType::class, $equipo, array(
        'action' => "crearEquipo",
        'em' =>  $emCatalogo,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => "form"
        )
     ));

     $form->handleRequest($request);

     if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

         $equipo = $form->getData();

         $emAdeq->persist($equipo);

         $emAdeq->flush();

         $this->addFlash('exito', $equipo->getId());

         return $this->redirectToRoute('portadaAdelantoEquipos');
     }
    ...
```

5. When I go to save the new *Equipo* it tells me that it was found a new entity in the relationship and should be saved (reffering to Modelo associated), but that entity is not new, it is an existing *Modelo* that is now related to the *Equipo*.
   [image]

As shown in the image, I choose a *Modelo* of the existing ones through an autocomplete field.

Just before doin the `$emAdeq->persist($equipo)` of the entity, i can see in the debugger the object that I am going to save it appears well composed:
[image]

The **Error** is the next:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\Equipo#modelo' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo@0000000011088ca600000000661c7dca. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo#__toString()' to get a clue.

I dont understand why thinks that is a new entity and why give me this string refering to modelo:

**Why this happends?
How can i save the *Equipo* with his relationship?**
Without make a persist of the *Modelo* because i can not save the *Modelo* that allready exist!

I have seen other example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771285/symfony2-doctrine-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship). But this does not work to me...

I run this command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` and everything is right.

Comment: i'm doing something worng steps before... i can not localize the problem, if is in the model..controller..form.. :'-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was using two **entityManager** because the relationship is made in **two** different databases.

But I have not realized that the related entity has **his database established**, so I only need **one** EntityManager.

With **one entityManager** i can ask for one entity and the relations without other EntityManagers

By having two entityManagers I was asked to saved twice.

**Solution:**

Establish in the entity his DB: `* @ ORM \ Table (name = "advanced equipment.")` Where I have used $emCatalgo replace it with $emAdeq and eliminate the catalog because it is unusable.

Thanks to [@Alessandro Minoccheri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348332/doctrine-tell-me-new-entity-was-found-when-i-set-a-relationship-manytoone-but?answertab=active#tab-top) because his answer is also valid but that make my realize what im doing wrong with 2 EntittyManagers.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `cascade persist` into your entity or you can change this:

```
$emAdeq->persist($equipo);
```

to this:

```
$emAdeq->merge($equipo);
```

Comment: I cant set cascade persist in my entity because it try to save the entity `Modelo` wich allready exist. Im gonna try the merge, ty!

Comment: Ok, try with merge an let me know please @Oscar

Comment: Weel done man!! that works in some way. Because solve my problem.. but that have made me think. Im gonna publish my own response mentionen you.

Comment: great! glad to help you! @Oscar